Why can't this trigonometric formula work?
The question is not intended to solve the ODE. The purpose of presenting the ODE is to give backgounds.
By solving a differential equation
$$
\sqrt{1-y^2}\mathrm{d}x+\sqrt{1-x^2}\mathrm{d}y=0
$$
we get the solution $\arccos(x)+\arccos(y)=\alpha.$ (corrected mistaken)
Then, we have
$$
xy-\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)}=\cos{\alpha}
$$
and
$$
x\sqrt{1-y^2}\color{red}{+}y\sqrt{1-x^2}=\sin{\alpha}
$$
But when I try to derive from $\sqrt{1-\cos^2\alpha}=\sin\alpha$, it becomes quite messy
$$
\sqrt{1-\left(xy-\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)}\right)^2}\stackrel{?}{=}\sin{\alpha}
$$
which I could not simplify to $\sin\alpha$.

How did you get the solution $\sec(x)+\sec(y)=\alpha$?

Sorry, it was suddenly lost and mistaken typing for $\cos^{-1}x$.

See the edit of my answer.

What are you trying to show? Are you trying to verify that $\arccos x + \arccos y = \alpha$ is a solution?

Sorry to make a big fuzz about a simple derivation which was missed by my own lazy ignorance.
Now the answer is clear.
Let's split the solution $\arccos(x)+\arccos(y)=\alpha$ to the ODE as $\cos{a}=x$ and $\cos{b}=y$, i.e., $a+b=\alpha$. Therefore, we have
\begin{align}
\sqrt{1-\cos^2{\alpha}}&=\sqrt{1-\left(xy-\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)}\right)^2}\\
&=\sqrt{1-\left(\cos{a}\cos{b}-\sqrt{\sin^2{a}\sin^2{b}}\right)^2}\\
&=\sqrt{1-\left(\cos{a}\cos{b}-\sin{a}\sin{b}\right)^2}\\
&=\sqrt{1-\cos^2(a+b)}\\
&=\sqrt{1-\cos^2\alpha}\\
&=\sin{\alpha}.
\end{align}

The solution is $\arccos(x) + \arccos(y) = \alpha$
You probably misinterpreted $\cos^{-1}(x)$ as $\frac{1}{\cos(x)} = \sec(x)$, instead of the inverse of the $\cos$ function.
Unfortunately, the notation for the inverse of a function is $f^{-1}$
, the same for raising $f$ to the power $-1$.
Edit: After the previous mistake was fixed you have another one:
This $x\sqrt{1-y^2}-y\sqrt{1-x^2}=\sin{\alpha}$ is wrong. It should be $x\sqrt{1-y^2}+y\sqrt{1-x^2}=\sin{\alpha}$.

Yes, you are right. I raised the question but was afraid of unlcear conditions and then added the ODE wiith its solution meanwhile trying to avoid $-1$ index without thinking.

(Edit: Since this answer was posted, O.P. had adjusted the original question to correct their solution to the o.d.e.) I don't think your solution is correct: A correct general solution should probably have special behavior at $x = \pm 1$, $y = \pm 1$, where the original equation has a singularity.
Hint The equation is separable, giving
$$\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1 - y^2}} = -\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} .$$
But both sides have elementary antiderivatives. In fact, the solutions are the loci of quadratic polynomials, hence they are (possibly degenerate) plane conics.

The solutions are $$x^2 + 2 t x y + y^2 = 1 - t^2, \qquad t \in [-1, 1] .$$ The discriminant $\Delta := 1 - t^2$ is nonnegative, so the solutions are ellipses (and, when $\Delta = 0$, i.e., $t = \pm 1$, degenerate ellipses). By symmetry their axes lie along $y = \pm x$.


Yes, you are right. I did not start from the first ODE equation.
